# Difference between `:path` and `:url` in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

As a default, I have the following configured in my *test* environment only. (Other tiers use Amazon S3 as storage)

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] =
  ":rails_root/public/system/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] =
  "/system/:rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:filename"
```

I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between the `:path` and `:url` options here and when to use which. Some basic Googling tells me the `url` is the universally accessible path whereas `path` is a local storage path.

Is there any reason those are really ever different, and should I bother keeping them different on the test environment? My problem is that I'm calling `<my_attachment>.url` in my spec tests but it's not finding it because it's actually stored in the location defined by `path`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`path` returns the relative location. For example:

> /images/example.jpg

`url`, on the other hand, returns the absolute location, just like in Rails route helpers.

> http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg

So, if you are displaying an image on your website. Refer to it using `path` since it will be related to your current url and domain.

If you are want to send it through an api to a 3rd party application, add it to an outbound email from your application or other similar scenarious, you should use the `url` method. I guess it will be the same with your tests and test environment. I hope this clears your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The `path` defines the location where your files will be stored. The `url` defines the location where your files can be accessed publicly. By default, the path will be composed using what you defined for your URL:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options
=> {:url=>"/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
    :path=>":rails_root/public:url", ...}
```

Usually will be suffice to define `url`.

From the `paperclip` docs:

> Files on the local filesystem (and in the Rails app's public directory) will be available to the internet at large. If you require access control, it's possible to place your files in a different location. You will need to change both the :path and :url options in order to make sure the files are unavailable to the public. Both :path and :url allow the same set of interpolated variables.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage